# Poisson goodness-of-fit of small sample

Tags: self-study, poisson-distribution, goodness-of-fit, small-sample

Please note that I have no background in statistics - this is for personal interest.

The post is inspired by a question at work.

We were given data by another department asserting that for a continuously advertised position there were zero applications in 6 consecutive days, followed by 7 applications on the 7<sup>th</sup> day. The validity of the data was questioned.

I wondered what the probability was of getting this exact result on seven consecutive days, assuming a homogeneous Poisson distribution. The below may or may not be correct.

$P(X=k) = \frac{{e^{-\lambda}}\lambda^k}{k!}$

So,

$P(X=0) = {\frac{{e^{-\lambda}}\lambda^0}{0!}}={e^{-\lambda}}$

$P(X=7) = {\frac{{e^{-\lambda}}\lambda^7}{7!}} =  {\frac{{e^{-\lambda}}\lambda^7}{5040}}$

$P(X=\{0,0,0,0,0,0,7\}) = \frac{{(e^{-\lambda})}^6{e^{-\lambda}}\lambda^7}{5040} = \frac{e^{-7\lambda}\lambda^7}{5040}$

Finding the value of $\lambda$ that gives the maximum likelihood for $P(X=\{0,0,0,0,0,0,7\})$,

${\frac{\partial}{\partial\lambda}}\frac{e^{-7\lambda}\lambda^7}{5040}$
$ = {\frac{1}{5040}}\frac{\partial}{\partial\lambda}{e^{-7\lambda}}\lambda^7$

Using the product rule,

${\frac{d}{dx}}(uv) = v{\frac{du}{dx}} + u{\frac{dv}{dx}}$ , where $u = {e^{-7\lambda}}$, $v = {\lambda^7}$, $x = \lambda$ gives:

${\frac{d}{d\lambda}}({e^{-7\lambda}}{\lambda^7}) = {\lambda^7}{\frac{d}{d\lambda}}{e^{-7\lambda}} + {e^{-7\lambda}}{\frac{d}{d\lambda}}{\lambda^7}$

Using the chain rule,

${\frac{dg}{dx}} = {\frac{dg}{du}}{\frac{du}{dx}}$ , where $g = e^{u}$, $x = \lambda$, $u = -7\lambda$ gives:

${\frac{d}{d\lambda}}e^{-7\lambda} = {\frac{d}{du}}e^u{\frac{d}{d\lambda}}-7\lambda$
$ = {-7e^{-7\lambda}}$

So,

${\frac{d}{d\lambda}}({e^{-7\lambda}}{\lambda^7}) = {-7e^{-7\lambda}}{\lambda^7} + {7e^{-7\lambda}}{\lambda^6}$
$ = {7e^{-7\lambda}}{\lambda^6}(1 - \lambda) = 0$

$\lambda = \{0, 1\}$

So, with a maximum probability at $\lambda = 1$,

$P(X=\{0,0,0,0,0,0,7\}) = \frac{e^{-7}1^7}{5040} = \frac{1}{5040e^7} \approx \frac{1}{5527031}$

This seemed like pretty slim odds, but on reflection, it wasn't telling me much.
Out of an infinite number of possible outcomes, the chosen outcome had a 1 in 5.5 million chance of occurring.

My question - is there a good test to use to give an indication of how well this data fit a homogeneous Poisson process? What would the results of such as test actually tell me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good efforts and nice thinking. Just a few notes about your method and your conclusion.

Estimating $\lambda$ could have been done by using the mean which is also an estimator of lambda. $7applications / 7days=1$

This is indeed pretty slim, but some data more "usual" could get pretty slim odds too. The probability of a specific event is rarely the good approach to test an hypothesis. The event [0,2,1,1,1,2] would have a very very small probability too, but it does not appear as abnormal.

The best would have been to consider the range of *"what could have been seen as very weird data"* and compute the probability to get an event in this whole event list. But how to build this dataset is a tricky question.

One could also point out some real world effect there. On what basis can we say that this should follow a poisson law ? I am personally a late applicant, maybe many others are. Under this track, what you could do is to check if poisson law is a good fit for this data. Maybe this is what you wanted to do since the beginning. You could then continue your self-study journey by looking at how to do a **goodness of fit test** to check that ! I think it would be rejected. Edit : I reread your question, this is what you are specifically asking, I hope other comments would interest you anyway.

A last comment, more qualitative, is that by estimating the best $\lambda$ fitting your data, you overestimate the probability of these datas. If lambda was in reality a bit less or more, the probability of your single event would go down. This is (very very broadly) the idea of degree of freedom that you may encounter while doing a goodness of fit test.